# Pymssql - How to avoid syntax error "EOL while scanning string literal"

Tags: sql, python-3.x

I'm trying to query by the module pymssql using SELECT, FROM and WHERE. I'm getting a "SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal" when I run the script. I am not very familiar with SQL syntax, but I've run it at SQL. The code is the following:

```
import pymssql

server = 'ip'
username = 'user'
password = 'pswrd'

cnxn = pymssql.connect(server, username, password, "tempdb")
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

query = "SELECT \"TIME_A\", \"TIME_B\", \"NAME\", \"NAME_B\", SOMETHING, SOMETHINGMORE, \"GROUP ALPHA\" \
        FROM \"DATABASE\".\"db\".\"SUBDATABASE\"  \
        WHERE \"GROUP ALPHA\"=\'PEOPLE A\'        \
        OR \"GROUP ALPHA\"=\'PEOPLE B\'           \
        OR \"GROUP ALPHA\"=\'PEOPLE C\'           \
        OR \"GROUP ALPHA\"=\'PEOPLE D\'           \
        OR \"GROUP ALPHA\"=\'PEOPLE F\'           \
        OR \"GROUP ALPHA\"=\'PEOPLE E\' ";"
```

I need help to identify where's my syntax error to run it well, thank you for time reading my enquiry.

Comment: You tried running the same query directly against the database in sql management studio ? To me it looks like you don't need double quotes around the column names in SELECT. Also it should be simply `FROM DATABASE.db.SUBDATABASE.`

Comment: Also it should be `WHERE [GROUP ALPHA]=\'PEOPLE A\'` and so on.

Comment: The `";"` by the end isn't correct, the first quote closes the string then the second opens a new one you never close (reaching End Of Line as the error complains about)